# Python SQLite Error while trying to add to .db file

Tags: python, sqlite

I am getting this error when running the program and trying to insert data:

```
'sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error'
```

my code is as following:

```
import sqlite3
def insert_data(values):
    with sqlite3.connect("mrsimms.db")as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql ='Insert into Stock(Name,Type,RetailPrice,NumberInStock,)values(?,?,?,?,?)'
        cursor.execute(sql,values)
        db.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add = "y"
    while add == "y":
        Name = input("Please enter the Name: ")
        Type = input("Please enter the type of product: ")
        RetailPrice =input("Retail Price: ")
        NumberInStock = input('Please enter the amount in stock: ')
        AddNewStock = (ProductID,Name,Type,RetailPrice,NumberInStock)
        print(AddNewStock)
        insert_data(AddNewStock)
        add = input("Do you wish to add another record? (y/n) ")
        print()
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you forget to define ProductID?

Comment: Shouldn't `sql ='Insert into Stock(Name,Type,RetailPrice,NumberInStock,)values(?,?,?,?,?)'` be `sql ='Insert into Stock(Name,Type,RetailPrice,NumberInStock,ProductId)values(?,?,?,?,?)` ?

Comment: i put ProductID shouldnt be there, it puts a number there automatically. i removed it however it still doesnt work

Comment: Remove the comma between `NumberInStock` and `)values(`.

Comment: `sql ='INSERT INTO Stock (Name, Type, RetailPrice, NumberInStock) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'`